# Cast multidimensional array from JSONObject

Tags: java, json

How can I fetch the `Object[][]` from a `JSONObject`? This is the code I'm using to complete this task:

```
Object[][] object2dArray= {{"String"},{315296487},{142736598.342},{"text"}};
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("String", "text");
json.put("int", 1234);
json.put("double", 123.0);
json.put("object2dArray", object2dArray);

System.out.println("json.get(\"String\") == "+json.get("String"));
outprint ==   json.get("String") == text

System.out.println("json.get(\"int\") == "+json.get("int"));
outprint ==   json.get("int") == 1234

System.out.println("json.get(\"double\") == "+json.get("double"));
outprint ==   json.get("double") == 123.0

System.out.println("json.get(\"object2dArray\") == "+json.get("object2dArray"));
outprint ==   json.get("object2dArray") == [[Ljava.lang.Object;@12a3a380
```

How shall I write the code to actually be able fetch a multidimensional     object array from a JSONObject?

Comment: If I just print json.toString(); then it is correct it shows all data, even the multidimensial array, here is an example of that

json.toString() == {"double":123,"object2dArray":[["String"],[315296487],[38.342],["text"]],"String":"text","int":1234}    

Im just wondering if it is possible to get the ,ultidimensial array or if the json only can take primitive datatypes.


Thanks!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The output

> [[Ljava.lang.Object;@12a3a380

is actually the **toString()** representation of the array **object2dArray**. You could validate it by the following:

```
System.out.println(object2dArray.toString());
```

As far as I know, there is no built in java method to print it like the following (unfortunately, you will have to write code to do that)

```
{{"String"},{315296487},{142736598.342},{"text"}};
```

**Sample Print:**
If you wish to print it, you will have to first cast the object returned like so:

```
Object[][] newRef = (Object[][]) js.get("object2dArray"));
```

Then loop over the object array and print it.

```
for(Object[] arr : newRef) {
    for (Object item : arr) {
        System.out.println(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the JSON object as a 2D array, just cast it:

```
Object[][] newRef = (Object[][])json.get( "object2dArray" );
```

Apache Commons has the [ReflectionToStringBuilder](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/ReflectionToStringBuilder.html) which is very handy for `toString()`'ing arbitrary objects that doesn't override `Object.toString()`, eg.:

```
 ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString( object2dArray );
```

Cheers,